# Map from 2 different nodes to duplicated target node

Tags: xslt, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have this source and target :
[image]

I need that my map would produce a target with 2 nodes of "T".

The first one is with "A" source content, and the second is with "B" source content.

For example:

Input:

```
<Root>
 <A>
   <FieldA>FA</FieldA>
   <FieldB>FB</FieldB>
 </A>
 <B>
   <FieldC>FC</FieldC>
   <FieldD>FD</FieldD>
 </B>
</Root>
```

Requested Output:

```
<Root>
    <T>
      <F1>FA</F1>
      <F2>FB</F1>
    </T>
    <T>
      <F1>FC</F1>
      <F2>FD</F2>
    </T>   
</Root>
```

*** There is also a condition regarding the map from "B" to "T"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place looping functoid

```
A --> Looping Functoid --> T
B --> Looping Functoid --> T

FieldA --> F1
FieldB --> F2
FieldC --> F1
FieldD --> F2
```

Comment: Great solution, but I have another small problem. 
A is unbounded, so the looping functoid creates an unnecessary T node.. how can I get over it ?

Comment: @ohadinho What do you mean 'unnecessary'. This map will create T nodes for each A and for each B.

Comment: because A is unbounded, it creates 3 nodes instead of 2. 
2 are good, and another one that's empty <T><F1></F1><F2></F2></T>

Comment: @ohadinho It isn't because A is unbounded. Something else is happening here. Try to validate your map (RightMouse --> Validate Map) and you'll see generated xsl.

Answer (score 0):

The following does what you want to achieve:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Root">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="A|B">
  <xsl:element name="T">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[parent::A or parent::B]">
  <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="./name() = 'FieldA' or ./name() = 'FieldC'">
        <xsl:element name="F1">
           <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:element name="F2">
           <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
     </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Besides, please take the time to report on what you have tried so far. SO is not there to do your homework. So, show your effort in your future questions.

Answer (score 0):

Just link A and B to T through a Looping Functoid.

Comment: Great solution, but I have another small problem. 
A is unbounded, so the looping functoid creates an unnecessary T node.. how can I get over it ?

Comment: Can you follup up with a sample?  T would only get created for each A & B so if an A is unnecesary, you'd need to add a filter to suppress the one you don't want.